# Can i add a Navigation Controller to a ModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I want to present a Modal view in the middle of the screen in on an iPad. This view will have a search bar and a table view. It will present search results. This is up and running.

Now i need to add a navigation controller so that upon touching a row in the above table view, a detail view will be pushed in from the right to allow the user to determine if this is the item he wanted.

I tried adding a navigation controller to my modal view but it doesn't display and i couldn't find a tutorial for this.

Can someone please give me a hint?

*EDIT: I'm starting to think that i first need to push a modal navigation controller and then add the tableview to this, is this the correct approach? Can someone please give some details on this if that's the case?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You have to present the NavigationController modal. Your ViewController will be the rootViewController of the UINavigationController.

I posted some code in [Adding UINavigationController to existing UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957878/adding-uinavigationcontroller-to-existing-uiviewcontroller/4958282#4958282)

Comment: Wow.. amazing. One line of code did it all. Added 
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease]; before presenting my modal controller.

Thank you SO much!